# Prevent user from going back to certain routes using route guards Angular

Tags: angular

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent users from going back to certain routes

now basically my issue is, a user will login and go through the `login/callback` route which authenticates the user and decides where they go from there, now if a user presses the browser back and goes back to that route they get stuck there
I have more examples but this is the easiest to understand

so I basically want to put a routeGuard on these routes that says something if user pressed back return them to there current route

now I know I can use the `canActivate()` and set something up like this

```
export class PreventBackGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router)

  canActivate(): boolean {
    // do something here
    console.log(this.activatedRoute);
  }
}
```

so I know I can get the current route (the route I'm going to) via the `activatedRoute` but I can't seem to get the route I was on previously though and I'm not sure how I would know when a user navigated to that route via the back button.. does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to get previous root if you add auth gaurd to your root and it returns false in canActivate method then it will not let user go to next root so user will stay on same page so in case of your login page example your canActivate method should look like

```
canActivate(): boolean {
     if(userLoggedIn){
         return false;
      }
    return true
  }
```

In this way if user is already logged in it will not allow them to visit login page and force them to stay on same page